# How do I calculate the closest power of 2 or 10 a number is?

Tags: algorithm, math

What is the most efficient way to cacluate the closest power of a 2 or 10 to another number? e.g.

3.5 would return 4 for power of 2 and 1 for power of 10

123 would return 128 for power of 2 and 100 for power of 10

0.24 would return 0.25 for power of 2 and 0.1 for power of 10

I'm just looking for the algorithm and don't mind the language.

Comment: I would think that 3.5 ought to be closer to 2^2 than 2^1

Comment: Similarly, 10^0 = 1 should be closer to 3.5 than 10^1 = 10.

Comment: Thanks EvilTeach - I've corrected that. 
Adam - I'm not sure your comment is correct, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Nick, I myself am sure that Adam's comment is correct.

Comment: You need to define *closer*: smaller *difference* or *ratio* from larger to smaller?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
n^round(log_n(x))
```

where log_n is the logarithm to base n. You may have to modify the round() depending on how you define "closest".

Note that `log_n(x)` can be implemented as:

```
log_n(x) = log(x) / log(n)
```

where `log` is a logarithm to any convenient base.

Comment: In many popular languages n^x will return the bitwise exclusive or of n and x.

Comment: Wedge: Yes, of course. I am using mathematical notation (within the bounds of ASCII) rather than a specific programming language.

Comment: Normal rounding to the nearest integer gives 10^n [or 2^n] for values >= 10^(n-0.5) [or 2^(n-0.5)]. I assume that's what you mean by "depending on how you define closest"

Answer (score 5):

For power of 2 on integers, there is a smart trick that consist of copying the last bit over and over to the right. Then, you only have to increment your number and you have your power of 2.

```
int NextPowerOf2(int n)
{
   n |= (n >> 16);
   n |= (n >> 8);
   n |= (n >> 4);
   n |= (n >> 2);
   n |= (n >> 1);
   ++n;
   return n;
}
```

Comment: Note that this algorithm is for 32 bits.  It also raises powers of two to the next value (for example, 4 will give 8).  To change the bitness, add or remove terms so that the first term is half of the number of bits you have.  To keep power of twos as is, simply subtract one at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

For power of 2 and >= 1 you can see how many times you can bit shift right.  For each time this is 1 extra power of 2 you are taking away.   Once you get down to 0 you have your number.

Answer (score 1):

> You may have to modify the round() depending on how you define "closest".

@Greg Hewgill's answer is correct except it rounds up too early for the examples you gave. For example, 10^round(log_10(3.5)) == 10, not 1. I'm assuming that's what he means by 'how you define "closest"'.

Probably the simplest way to use Greg's formula and if it's too high (or too low for x < 1), use the next lower power of two:

```
closest = n ^ round(log_n(x))

if (closest > x) {
    other = closest / n
} else {
    other = closest * n
}

if (abs(other - x) < abs(closest - x)) {
    return other
} else {
    return closest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I might approach the problem, but using log base 2 and log base 10.

log10 of (123) is 2.something.
take the floor of that
then raise 10 to that power, and that ought to get you close.

the same thing ought to work with log base 2.

log2 of (9) is 3.something
take the floor of that
then raise to to that power

you might play with rounding of the log.

Answer (score 0):

to play off of Vincent Roberts trick, I just worked out a way to get the bit hacks to round to the nearest power of two not just always round to the next power of two.

```
private static int ClosestPowerOfTwo(int v) {
    //gets value of bit to the right of leading bit and moves it to left by 1
    int r = (v & (v>>1))<<1; 
    //rs bit in same place as vs leading bit is 1 to round up or 0 to round down.
    v >>= 1;
    //replaces leading bit with a 1 if rounding up or leaves 0 if rounding down.
    v |= r; 
    //Next power of 2 exclusive
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v++;
    return v;
}
```